# Taylor explansion of the feed-forward network error

Tags: neural-networks, taylor-series

The Optimal Brain Damage paper proposes to approximate the error objective function by a Taylor series.

[image]

Is E a generic error function? And how is the formula (1) obtained?

The paper:
http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=14BC0EC4F265274DC39819692566F249?doi=10.1.1.32.7223&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard Taylor series expansion for a multidimensional (e.g. vector) function. References are most standard n-dimensional calculus books, or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html